# Is it possible to allow nginx to start if the specified certificate/keys files are absent?

Tags: nginx

I have following situation: I have an nginx instance serving a few websites like this:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name website1.com;
  root /var/www/website1;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/website1.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/website1.key;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name website2.com;
  root /var/www/website2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/website2.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/website2.key;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www/acme;

  # Allow files to be served for the use of acme certification only
  try_files $uri @redirect;

  location @redirect {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Now I ended with the chicken and the egg problem where:

1. Without certificates nginx will crash
2. To generate certificates I need to serve `/var/www/acme` files
3. To serve those file I need nginx running

I know I can manually remove uncertified vhosts from configuration, generate the certificates and then reenable it, but this will be a pain to automate in ansible.

Also I cannot disable nginx and use standalone certbot instance, since I need to be able to add websites without interfering with already existing websites.

In apache I was able to do this:

```
<IfFile /etc/ssl/certs/$name.crt>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  </VirtualHost>
</IfFile>
```

Is there a similar feature in nginx, or at least a way to prevent errors in one of the vhosts from killing the entire server?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to start nginx with the erroneous configuration. You have the following options instead:

#### 1. Using a dummy self-signed certificate to allow nginx to start

This one probably will be the most simple. The trick is that nginx does not require valid certificates/keys to start - it can be any self-signed certificate, it won't prevent LetsEncrypt from verifying the ACME challenge. You can generate a pair of the self-signed certificate/key using the following one-liner:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -subj "/CN=localhost" -keyout /etc/ssl/private/website.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/website.crt
```

Use those certificate/key in your nginx config and replace them with the valid ones after nginx will be started; then reload nginx to reload new certificate/key.

#### 2. Using variables in the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives

[Since](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) nginx version 1.15.9 you can use variables in the `ssl_certificate`/`ssl_certificate_key` directives parameters:

> Changes with nginx 1.15.9                                        26 Feb 2019
>
> *) Feature: variables support in the `ssl_certificate` and
> `ssl_certificate_key` directives.

There are some caveats when you are using variables with those directives. You can't do something like

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name website1.com;
  root /var/www/website1;
  set $site website1;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/$site.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/$site.key;
  ...
}
```

As being pointed by [Maxim Dounin](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1744#comment:2), variables set with the `set` directive of the rewrite module are only available after rewrite instructions were evaluated when processing a request as it described in the rewrite module [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html). As such, these variables won't have any meaningful value during an SSL handshake. When loading certificates you have to use builtin connection-related variables, or custom variables which are always available - such as provided with [`map`](http://nginx.org/r/map), [`geo`](http://nginx.org/r/geo), [`perl_set`](http://nginx.org/r/perl_set), or [`js_set`](http://nginx.org/r/js_set) directives.

That is, instead you can define a `map` block at the `http` configuration level:

```
map $server_name $site {
    website1.com  website1;
    website2.com  website2;
    ...
    default       dummy;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name website1.com;
  root /var/www/website1;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/$site.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/$site.key;
  ...
}

...
```

Note that the `$server_name` variable will be equal to the first argument of the `server` directive value. That is, it will be equal to `website1.com` if your `server_name` directive will look like

```
server_name website1.com www.website1.com;
```

and it will be equal to `www.website1.com` if your `server_name` directive will look like

```
server_name www.website1.com website1.com;
```

no matter if the actual request will be `https://website1.com/` or `https://www.website1.com`. You can find out more details [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/706438/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-variables-host-http-host-and-server-na). Another variable to be mapped can be the [`$ssl_server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_server_name).

**Caution!** According to [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate), using variables implies that a certificate will be loaded for each SSL handshake, and this may have a negative impact on performance. I don't know what the amount of performance impact really is; most probably it is related to your current [`open_file_cache`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#open_file_cache) (and related) settings. However if you still want to choose certificates/keys dynamically and want to avoid that performance impact, you have the third option.

#### 3. Using variables for `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives data

[Since](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) nginx version 1.15.10 you can use variables for specifying `ssl_certificate`/`ssl_certificate_key` directives data directly:

> Changes with nginx 1.15.10                                       26 Mar 2019
>
> *) Feature: loading of SSL certificates and secret keys from variables.

To use this you should declare your certificate/key the following way:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.com;
    ssl_certificate     data:$site_cert;
    ssl_certificate_key data:$site_key;
    ...
}
```

I did this trick in the past, and since there are some really non-obvious configuration steps involved, and I didn't find any working example of how to do it right at the time I was solving this task, I'm going to show how it can be done to made a question somewhat more complete.

The cert/key data should be specified in a single line, with a newlines being replaced with the escaped `\n` special character. Here is an example defaulting to self-signed certificate/key:

```
map $server_name $site_cert {
    include /etc/ssl/certs/*.conf;
    default "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
}

map $server_name $site_key {
    include /etc/ssl/private/*.conf;
    default "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nxzPH0XOM8P4jMgkcTBYP+g==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
}
```

To get the `.conf` map block line from the key/cert, I'm using the following scripts:

- `get_key_line.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "$1 \""; while read line; do echo -n "$line\\n"; done <$2; echo "\";"
```

- `get_cert_line.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "$1 \""; while read line; do echo -n "$line\\n"; done <$2; echo "$cert_r3\";"
```

These scripts are to be invoked in the following way:

```
# get_cert_line.sh website.com /etc/ssl/certs/website.crt >/etc/ssl/certs/website.conf
# get_key_line.sh website.com /etc/ssl/private/website.key >/etc/ssl/private/website.conf
```

Did you notice the script difference and the `$cert_r3` part? That's because of nginx limitation of the configuration file line length, which is about 4K characters. This limitation makes impossible to include the full certificates chain with a single configuration line, so I finished up with the variables interpolation, with the every certificate map line looking as

```
website "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n<cert data here>-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n$cert_r3";
```

and including an additional block to my nginx configuration file:

```
geo $cert_r3 {
    default "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nnLRbwHOoq7hHwg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
}
```

(Well, actually at the times this was written, I used two chained blocks including both `R3` and `ISRG Root X1` certificates, however the second one is not really needed anymore nowadays.)

**Caution!** Nginx documentation warns about the security implications of this syntax usage, such as writing secret key data to error log. As for me, possibility of exposing the key data via enabled [SSI mechanism](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) looks somewhat more dangerous.